# kubectl deploy from within kubernetes container

Tags: jenkins, kubectl, tekton

How do you deploy from within Kubernetes container - using CI/CD?

Senario:

1. I am building within Kubernetes using [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko)
2. Now how to run kubectl within Kuberneters. And I do have the right serviceAccount for it. First problem is to have a container ready for executing kubectl.

Note: `- /bin/cat`

I found this, but it give errors:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kubectl-deploy
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kubectl
    image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /bin/cat
    tty: true
```

Errors:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  78s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kubectl-deploy to master
  Normal   Pulled     76s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 874.059036ms
  Normal   Pulled     74s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 860.59161ms
  Normal   Pulled     60s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 859.31958ms
  Normal   Pulling    33s (x4 over 77s)  kubelet            Pulling image "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
  Normal   Created    32s (x4 over 76s)  kubelet            Created container kubectl
  Normal   Started    32s (x4 over 76s)  kubelet            Started container kubectl
  Normal   Pulled     32s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "bitnami/kubectl:latest" in 849.398179ms
  Warning  BackOff    7s (x7 over 73s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: What kind of project are you going to deploy?

Comment: I am pushing containers to public dockerHub, so first off just public dockerHub.

Comment: https://github.com/dreambold/kubernetes/tree/master/pods Here's the sample pod yml and some commands for you to run to start

Comment: Sorry, but is this not "only" standard kubectl commands - note I am looking for running kubectl from within a container in kubernetres. Deploying from within a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found this, but it give errors

When you run a Pod in Kubernetes, by default, it expect it to be a *long running service*. But in your case, you run a *one-off command* that terminates immediately. To run *one-off commands* in Kubernetes, it is easiest to run them as [Kubernetes Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

> First problem is to have a container ready for executing kubectl.

Since you are using Tekton, have a look at the "deploy task" from [Tekton Hub](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/kubectl-deploy-pod), it is configured with an image that includes `kubectl`.